# Как получить доступ к элементу кортежа по типу и индексу? С++

Tags: c++, структуры, типы-данных, индексы, кортежи

Есть структура, с помощью которой делают массив структур:

```
struct A
{ 
  string A;
  int B;
  int C;
  int D;
}
```

Для этого массива существует функция сортировки, в которую принимается индекс поля структуры. Она должна быть универсальной для этих 4 полей

```
template<typename Tvalue>
void SortBy(int FieldIndex)
```

В ходе работы создаётся кортеж из этих полей.
**Вопрос:** 
Как получить доступ к элементу кортежа по типу Tvalue и индексу, если тип string встречается два раза в кортеже?

Comment: А каждый тип индексируется отдельно?

Comment: Для меня ваш вопрос не понятен, но мне кажется вы пытаетесь усложнять свою задачу. Думаю нужно пересмотреть подход решения

Comment: Индекс выбирается во время выполнения, или фиксирован во время компиляции?

Comment: Индекс выбирается во время исполнения

Comment: На будущее, пожалуйста пишите в коментариях-ответах `@username`, иначе нам не приходят уведомления.

Comment: Может, я не понял условие, но почему не сделать сравнение через лямбду, которая выбирает нужное поле? Структура ведь у вас фиксированная, не параметр шаблона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите, это то что нужно? Извлекать элементы кортежа одновременно по номеру и типу невозможно, так что в примере только номер. Номер должен быть известен на этапе компиляции.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{ 
    std::string A;
    int B;
    int C;
    int D;
};

static A a[4] = {{"str1", 1, 8, 3},
    {"str2", 2, 1, 4},
    {"strstr", 4, 3, 2},
    {"dffsdf", 5, 3, 5},
};

template <int FieldIndex>
void SortBy()
{
    auto cmp = [](const A &left, const A &right){
        auto tl = std::make_tuple(left.A, left.B, left.C, left.D);
        auto tr = std::make_tuple(right.A, right.B, right.C, right.D);
        return std::get<FieldIndex>(tl) < std::get<FieldIndex>(tr);
    };
    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a), cmp);
}

void print(A &row)
{
    std::cout << row.A << " " << row.B << " " << row.C << " " << row.D << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Before: " << std::endl;
    for (auto it = std::begin(a); it < std::end(a); ++it)
    {
        print(*it);
    }
    SortBy<2>();
    std::cout << "After: " << std::endl;
    for (auto it = std::begin(a); it < std::end(a); ++it)
    {
        print(*it);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/zaNRWBGgIt

Comment: Это решение в целом удовлетворяет условию, спасибо за ваш ответ

Comment: @Bucephalus, но вы же написали выше: "Индекс выбирается во время исполнения".

Comment: Как я правильно понял: Других вариантов, кроме как получения доступа к элементам кортежа во время именно компиляции, быть не может. Поэтому здесь, видимо, что-то из разряда switch нужно использовать

Comment: @Bucephalus Аналог switch можно сгенерировать автоматически, особенно если взять что-то типа https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get. Но это все сложно, и ради 4 полей этим заниматься не хочется.

Comment: @maestro Вместо `std::make_tuple` лучше взять `std::tie`, чтобы лишний раз не копировать все поля.